# Manipulation of HTML values in a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML structure

```
<div class="something">
    <div class="amount">$10</div> 
</div> 
<div class="something">
    <div class="amount">$20</div> 
</div> 
<div class="something">
    <div class="amount">$30</div> 
</div> 
<div class="something">
    <div class="amount">$40</div> 
</div>
```

I want to manipulate the amount displayed on the page based on a condition. Eg: Increase the fontsize if the amount is above $25. I am able to select and manipulate the style without the condition. I tried using makeArray to store the values from the amount class but i am not sure how to do the conditional check.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".amount").each(function(){
        var amount = parseInt($(this).text().replace("$",""));
        $(this).css({fontSize:amount});
});
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HU9mV/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.something div.amount").addClass(function () {
  var amount = parseFloat($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
  if (!isNaN(amount) && amount > 25) {
    return "special";
  }
});
```

This adds the CSS class "special" to every div.amount that has a value greater than 25.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be one way to do it:

```
// iterate through all .amount divs
$('div.amount').each(function() {
    var jqThis = $(this);
    var text = jqThis.text().replace("$","");

    // if the dollar value as a number is greater than 25, change the font
    if((+text) > 25) {
        this.css('font-size', '16px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.something > .amount').each(function() {
    var amt = $(this).text().substring(1);
    if(parseInt(amt) > 25) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

parseFloat can be used also if you expect floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As written you could use the jQuery.each method like so.

```
$("div.something>div.amount").each(function(i,e) {
  $me = $(e);
  if($me.text().substr(1) > 25) {
    $me.animate({ fontSize: 25 }, 800)
  }
});
```

This is overkill for your exact question but would give you many options for conditional checks and further actions.  For instance the i (index) could be used to tell which row(s) were changed and the e (element) variable makes the entire inner div available for manipulation.